# Setting a limit to user input for a big number C#

Tags: c#

I am new to coding and I am making a program where the user deposits money into his account. I have made it so the user can only deposit no more than 1 million dollars. I'm having trouble with making it run. When I run it, it underlines the Convert.ToInt64. I have tried it without the Convert.ToInt but it underlines te Console.ReadLine This is what I've got so far:

```
public static void userbalance(string firstname, string middlename, string lastname, string userpin)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations " + firstname + " your account has now been set!");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("You will now have to deposit money into your account NOTE you can only deposit no more than 1 million");
    Console.Write("Now, how much money do you want to deposit in your bank account " + firstname + " " + lastname + " ? (Enter in digits please)");
    int userbank = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

    if (userbank > 1000000 || userbank < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid deposit please try again");
        userbalance(firstname, middlename, lastname, userpin);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your deposit was successful, now your bank balance is $" + userbank);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Side note: don't recurse for the purpose of reprompting. Use a loop.

Comment: We can't help unless we know what's wrong with the current outcome.

Comment: This is not legal syntax: `int userbank = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());`, There is no implicit conversion from an `Int64` to an `int`. That compile error would keep this from running. You could use `Convert.ToInt32` instead, although `int.TryParse` is generally more preferrable. As others have stated, please let us know the exact error or problem you're encountering.

Comment: The error is as @RufusL wrote in comments.  You could fix by using `int.TryParse()` or by declaring `userbank` as a `long` and doing `long.TryParse()`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that this is not legal syntax: `int userbank = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());`, because there is no implicit conversion from an `Int64` to an `int`.

You could use `Convert.ToInt32` instead, although `int.TryParse` is generally more preferrable because it won't throw an exception if the conversion fails. Also, it returns a `bool` indicating success (and sets an `out` parameter to the converted value) so we can use it as part of a `while` condition that will loop until valid input is entered.

For example:

```
public static void UserBalance(string firstName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\nCongratulations, {firstName}, your account has now been set!\n");
    Console.Write("You will now have to deposit money into your account. ");
    Console.WriteLine("NOTE: you can only deposit no more than 1 million");
    Console.Write("\nEnter deposit amount in whole numbers only: ");

    // This is passed to int.TryParse and will be set to the converted value
    int depositAmount;

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out depositAmount)
            || depositAmount < 0
            || depositAmount > 1000000)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid deposit please try again");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.Write("\nEnter deposit amount in whole numbers only: ");
    }

    // Using the :C format specifier will format depositAmount as currency
    Console.WriteLine($"\nDeposit successful. Your bank balance is: {depositAmount:C}");
}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]